# PHP login script not working while user exist

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I have the following database login and query script in PHP:

```
require 'database.php';  

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('username FROM users WHERE username == :username');
    $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $records->execute();
    $result = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($result) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Succesfully logged in!')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error, wrong credentials.')</script>";
    }
}
```

But for some reason it's not working. I keep getting the error pop up, saying the input is wrong. `Database.php` is totally fine, as my registration form is correctly putting users in the database with that same file. Anyone with any idea?

Comment: Updated code formatting for readability

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
  // modification in below line: fetch password too
  $records = $conn->prepare('select username, password FROM users WHERE username == :username');
  $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $records->execute();
  $result = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($result) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])){
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Succesfully logged in!')</script>";
    } else {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error, wrong credentials.')</script>";
    }
}
```

Hope this would work

Comment: @TestT do one thing `echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);` print result array and post here!

Comment: Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => admin [password] => $2y$10$oF11nTMSvW/e7eHsR4R3p.k ) 3

Comment: check `password_verify()` function or post code for this function